# C# .NET 6 Interface default method implementation does not work as expected

Tags: c#, .net-core

In below code

```cs
public interface IXProcRow
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    void SetId(long id) { Id = id; }
}
public interface I1 : IXProcRow { }
public interface I2 : IXProcRow { }
public class C1 : I1
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
public class C2 : I2
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public void SetId(long id) { Console.Write("i am here"); }
}
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new C1();
        t1.SetId((long)0);
        var t2 = new C2();
        t2.SetId((long)0);
        return;
    }
}
```

I get the compile error `Program.cs(38, 12): [CS1061] 'C1' does not contain a definition for 'SetId' and no accessible extension method 'SetId' accepting a first argument of type 'C1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have tried to compile same code in .NET 7 but get the same error.

I expect `t1.SetId((long)0);` should run `{ Id = id; }`
and `t2.SetId((long)0);` should run `{ Console.Write("i am here"); }`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)? You need to invoke SetId on C1's interface: `IXProcRow t1 = new C1(); t1.SetId(0);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke SetId on C1's interface: `IXProcRow t1 = new C1(); t1.SetId(0);`

```cs
public interface IXProcRow
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    void SetId(long id) { Id = id; }
}

public interface I1 : IXProcRow { }

public class C1 : I1
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         IXProcRow t1 = new C1();
         t1.SetId(0);
    }    
}
```

Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: Or just cast inline `((IXProcRow) new C1()).SetId(0);`